# Nginx - Work with multiple codeigniter installation

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have a Nginx server (1.6), with PHP-FPM on my local server. 
I have multiple webapps in my "/var/www/" folder, like site01, site02...

My applications use CodeIgniter.

I want to have /var/www/site01 called on default location, and /var/www/site02 called when I go :

```
http://server/site02.
```

Here is my nginx default.conf :

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    access_log   off;
    client_body_buffer_size 1M;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    disable_symlinks off;

```
# Site 01
location / {
    root   /var/www/site01;
    index index.html index.php index.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

    location = /index.php {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 10000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16K;            
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;        
        include fastcgi_params; 
    }
}

# Site 2
location /site02 {
    root /var/www/;
    index index.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

    location ~ ^/site02/index.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        root /var/www/;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 10000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16K;            
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;        
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;  
    }
}
```

I have multiple errors, firstly, when I don't put "index.php" in my site02 URL, I have a 403 error. Then, I can't go any controller, it redirects me to /site01.

What is the best way to handle multiple PHP apps folders ? Why do I have these redirections ? Thanks.

Comment: You should not use `root` inside `location` blocks. Use `alias` directive instead. `alias /var/www/site02;` in your case instead of `root /var/www;` in your `location` block.

Answer (score 1):

First i see in your second site configuration :

```
location /site02 {
    root /var/www/;
    index index.htm;
```

CHANGE TO :

```
location /site02 {
    root /var/www/;
    index index.php index.htm;
```

need index.php

Comment: I will say "oh my god" ... Ok my first problem is resolved. Thanks ! But I have always these redirections.

Comment: I put a "die('Test site02');" on the first line of my index.php in site02. And I cannot see it.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem when I was developing 2 CodeIgniter application on one Nginx server. below code worked for me

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html/;
    server_name example.com;

    # Site 01
    location /site1 {
        alias /var/www/html/site1/;
        index index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /site1/index.php;
    }

    # Site 2
    location /site2 {
        alias /var/www/html/site2/;
        index index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /site2/index.php;
    }

    error_page 404 /error/404.php;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : excuse me , Try this :
ROOT /var/www if nginx is configured with this path

```
server{

......
......
root   /var/www/; 
index index.html index.php index.htm;

location / {                  
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;   

}    
# Site 1
location /site01 {
    .....your parameters here...
}

# Site 2
location /site02 {
    .....your parameters here...              
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;            
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 10000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16K;            
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;        
        include fastcgi_params;  
    }

}
```

more configuration is available on the nginx wiki (http://wiki.nginx.org/ServerBlockExample), please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Ok, hard to solve ! But this works for me :

```
location /site02 {
    root /var/www/;
    index index.php index.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /site02/index.php;

    location ~ ^/site02/(.+\.php)$ {
        root /var/www;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /site02/index.php;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 10000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16K;            
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;        
        include fastcgi_params; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name themainwebsite.test *.themainwebsite.test;
    root "C:/laragon/www/themainwebsite";

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        autoindex on;
    }

    # Site 2
    location /admin-dashboard{
        alias "C:/laragon/www/borneotropicalstream/admin-dashboard";
        index index.php index.htm ;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin-dashboard/index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass php_upstream;      
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    
    # deny the .htaccess file if exist
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ /admin-dashboard\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

This is my configuration. I put my admin page (built with Codeigniter v3) inside the codeigniter v3 main project. I'm using windows 10 and using Laragon (https://laragon.org) for web server management with PHP v7.4 and Nginx v1.22.0. I think this configuration can be implemented in other operating system.